# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window'

Tags: flutter, dart, cashfree

I have used cashfree for payment Integration. When I run the flutter web and click the pay button I get this error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': bpv(a){var s,r=this,q=A.bpc
if(!A.q6(r))if(!(r===t.ub))s=!1
else s=!0
else s=!0
if(s)q=A.bou
else if(r===t.K)q=...<omitted>...)} could not be cloned.
    at Cashfree.s.onload (https://sdk.cashfree.com/js/flutter/1.0.26/dropinClient.prod.js:1:3542)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your SDK from version 0.0.2(Beta version) to the latest version. Reach out to care@cashfree.com if you have any issues while doing the integration in future.